# What is the most modern, and secure way to use mysql with nodeJS(without php)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a webpage, using only javascript. I want to build a secure and reliable mysql connection with nodeJS, but I don't really know where to start. I also noticed, NodeJS doesn't have an improved mysql(mysqli) like php, so it seems really deprecated to me. "Only javascript" is a proper development method? Can I fully substitute php with nodeJS? Will I be able to prevent SQL Injections? Does it even make sense to leave php behind? Where, and when people use only javascript principle.

I found this code but it is really anemic: Can you suggest me an intermediate course or tutorial?

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');

   var con = mysql.createConnection({
   host: "localhost",
   user: "myusername",
   password: "mypassword"
   });

   con.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log("Connected!");
   });
```

Comment: This question is either too broad or asking for an external resource (which is also off topic). Please ask an answerable question as defined in the [help]

Comment: There are mysql drivers for Node.js and If you prepare and execute the statements, you don't need to worry much. Ofcourse, node has middlewares to sanitize too. So, in conclusion yes - you can have node.js and mysql production ready.

Comment: "I also noticed, NodeJS doesn't have an improved mysql(mysqli) like php" — PHP needed an improved MySQL library because the original was so awful. There's no need for every programming language to write a terrible library before throwing it out to have something reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you read a bit about [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/). In short it is an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) that sits between your Node application and Database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [MySQL](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) package which is absolutely not deprecated.

As an example, you can prevent SQL injections with [query values escaping](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values).

```
const sql = 'UPDATE users SET foo = ?, bar = ?, baz = ? WHERE id = ?';
connection.query(sql, ['a', 'b', 'c', userId], function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // ...
});
```